# How to include resx file in a Nuget package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, resources, nuspec

I have a .Net Framework 4.6.1 project from which I make a nuget package.  This nuget package simply installs 2 dlls and a couple of content files which is working fine.

The problem is that I now added resource string via a resx file that resides in:

```
~\App_Data\Global\Resources\resource-strings.resx
```

And I don't know how to make that file be part of the nuget package properly. When I create the .nupkg, I see the resx file there, but when I install it on another project, the resx file should be copied to the App_Data\Global\Resources folder, but it is not.

Is it possible?

From what I investigated, I think I also have to do something with the targets files + nuspec config, but nothing I have tried works.

I literally just need the resx file copied over. Nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: There is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507453/create-nuget-package-for-dot-net-core-project-from-static-files) which is related to yours. I hope you could give any  feedback or my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sure**. It is possible and can be done by nuget. Since you want this resource file be copied into your target asp net project folder, you could try the following steps:

=====================================================

**First**, if you want to install this `net461` nuget package into a `net framework` asp net project, you should use [content node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) in `xxx.nusepc` file

First, make sure that the **Build Action** of the resource-strings.resx is **Embedded Resource** rather than **Content**.

**1)** **first**, run cmd command :`cd xxxx(project folder path)` and then run `nuget spec` to generate the nuspec file. These are enough:

**2)** open the `nuspec` file and add the content node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>xxx</id>
        <version>xxx</version>
        <title>xxx</title>
        <authors>xxx</authors>
        ............       
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="~\App_Data\Global\Resources\resource-strings.resx(the path of the file in net framework 4.6.1 project)" target="content\App_Data\Global\Resources\resource-strings.resx" />
    </files>
</package>
```

**3)** then save the `nuspec` file and run `nuget pack` to generate the `nupkg`.

**Before** you install the nuget package, you should first [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) to remove the old wrong versions of the nuget.

When you install this package, the file will be copied into the root path `App_Data\Global\Resources\resource-strings.resx` of the web project.

====================================================

If you want to install this package into new sdk project(Net Core or xxx with **PackageReference** nuget management format), you could should create a target file with a copy task.

**1)** add a folder called build in the net framework 4.6.1 project and then add a file called `<Package_id>.props` file.

**Note** that you should make sure that the nuget package's id is the same as the `<Package_id>.props`. [Hint from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

**2)** add these in `<Package_id>.props`:

```
  <Project>
      <Target Name="CopyFilesToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="Copy resource-strings.resx  to project" />
        <ItemGroup>
          <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\**\*.*"/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy
           SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
           DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"/>
      </Target>
      
    </Project>
```

**3)** Modify the `xxx.nuspec` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <version>xxx</version>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>me</owners>
    ............
  </metadata>
 <files>
<file src="~\App_Data\Global\Resources\resource-strings.resx" target="content\App_Data\Global\Resources\resource-strings.resx" />
<file src="build\xxx(like package_id).props" target="build"/>
</files>

</package>
```

**4)** then you should use `nuget pack` command to pack this project. Before you install this package, you should first clean nuget caches first.

**After** you install this nuget package, you should **build** your project to run this custom copy target to copy the file into your main project.

**Also**, there is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348993/include-only-xml-file-of-specific-nuget-package-in-a-different-folder) about this.