# include the XML documentation from a NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I have a NuGet package with an xml documentation file (doc.xml).

I have installed the NuGet package in my project.

I know want to add the NuGet documentation file doc.xml to my solution.

I am running .net core 3.1 but I have no idea how this can be achieved.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Daniel, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your nuget project is `net standard` or `net core`, please check these steps:

**1)** create a file called `<package_id>.props` file under a folder called **build** on your project.

[image]

Note that, you should make sure that the your `package_id` of your nuget project is the same as the `.props` file, otherwise, it will not work. See [this link's description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

**In my side**, my nuget package called `test.1.0.0.nupkg`, so I should rename the file as `test.props` file.

**2)** please add these content in `test.props` file.

```
<Project>

    <Target Name="CopyFilesToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\File\*.*"/> 
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy
           SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
           DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)"     
        />
    </Target>


</Project>
```

**The propose of this target** is to copy the xml file from the **File** folder of the nupkg into the target project's folder when you install this nuget into the main project.

**3)** add these under `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\test.xml(the path of the xml file in your nuget project)" Pack="true" PackagePath="File"></None>
    <None Include="build\test.props(the path of the test.props file in your nuget project)" Pack="true" PackagePath="build"></None>
        
</ItemGroup>
```

**4)** Then, when you pack your project, the structure should be this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Before** you install this new version of nuget package, you should [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages` to remove the old ones in case you still install the old one.

**After that**, **rebuild** your main project to execute the target and you will see the xml document file exist under the main project folder.

[image]

**In addition**, there is [a similar issue you can refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348993/include-only-xml-file-of-specific-nuget-package-in-a-different-folder/63353505#63353505) and if you use the `net framework` project, the link also provide the method.

===========================

**Update 1**

If you want to copy the file into `bin\Release` or `bin\Debug`, you should modify **step 2**, change to use this in the `.props` file:

```
<Copy
     SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
    DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)"     
/>
```

or just

```
<Copy
   SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
   DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"     
  />
```

as you want.

**Before** you install this new version, you should first delete nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

Comment: WOW what a great answer! I will test this out ASAP and get back to you ASAP! Thanks

Comment: If I want to copy the xml file to the output directory (bin/Bebug, bin/Release etc.) how would I do that ?

Comment: Now I have DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)" but the xml file is not showing up in either bin/Debug nor bin/Release. It is not showing anywhere actually.

Comment: Sorry for that. You should use `$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)`:) Before you install this new version, you should first delete nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

Comment: Just one last thing, can I not use $(OutDir) instead ?

Comment: Sure. It is the same effect as you want. I have updated my answer and you can check it:)

Comment: Hi again. When I run this from VS it works, BUT, when I do it from Azure DevOps no file is being copied. It's super frustrating! Any suggestions ?