# XML documentation is in package but never copied to output directory

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0, nuget-package, xml-documentation

The generated package indeed includes the XML file next to the DLL file, however, when using the package from another project, the documentation is never copied to output directory.

Here are the relevant bits on how the package is generated:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Tried the suggested answers in the following questions but without success:

- [NuGet package XML documentation not visible in .NET Core 2.2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891727/nuget-package-xml-documentation-not-visible-in-net-core-2-2-app)
- [Documentation disappears in NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696015/documentation-disappears-in-nuget-package)
- [include the XML documentation from a NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044785/include-the-xml-documentation-from-a-nuget-package)

Also tried to clear the packages cache and restarting Visual Studio but that didn't have any effect.

**Question:**

How does one get the XML documentation to be copied to output directory for a .NET 6 package?

Comment: Are you building for release or something like that which might omit the XML?

Comment: No, currently I'm building under Debug configuration for the purpose of testing.

Comment: I ran a quick test of my own and like you, I don't see where the output is stored when setting `GenerateDocumentationFile` to true.
I do however get an output when I use `DocumentationFile` and manually set the path. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/output#documentationfile

Edit: I deleted the `DocumentationFile` and tested again with just `GenerateDocumentationFile` and I do indeed see the XML generated in my output folder. If you continue to get issues using both then maybe the issue is unrelated?

Comment: Another quick question. The XML Documentation file you are expecting, is that on the top level Exe or WinExe project, or is it in some kind of class Library? If it's in a class Library, are you doing a rebuild of the main executable or are you building the library on it's own? I just tested with documentation in a referenced assembly and it seems to generate the XML okay when I build the parent executable project but building the library on it's own might not prompt it to generate the XML again. Just a thought.

Comment: sorry about the spam.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044785/include-the-xml-documentation-from-a-nuget-package  I notice this link you shared is more about copying the generated XML into a package when you create a NuGet. In this case it's a question more about copying files from your output directory into the package and not so much to do with generating the XML in the first place.

Comment: You know what, something really interesting just happened, I tried with `DocumentationFile` and that didn't copy anything; then I checked in the consumer project whether IntelliSense shows up anything and it does actually! Then I tried removing `DocumentationFile` and regenerate the package, the documentation still shows up in consumer project. It appears that somehow, Visual Studio is able to fetch the documentation directly from `C:\users\username\.nuget\...`

Comment: I wonder if there would be an easy way to automatically find the location and copy it. I'm a bit confused what your source and target is, but if you need the documentation coming into your project or build then maybe something here can help automate the process?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022
e.g. copy from packages to output, or something like that?

Comment: Actually I'm generating a class library, I tried rebuilding one or the other as you suggested but that didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: I just made the following test, create new project with a class library with docs, reference generated package from a new console application; not even building the console application shows up documentation. Building the console application results in the same, no XML in output directory. Ultimately, if the behavior has changed and the documentation still shows up, I'm okay with that as long as it works.

Comment: Just one last comment before I part ways as I'm learning a bit here too as I go. I couldn't help but notice that there is no packages folder in the solution directory. As such I went searching for what environment variable you might be able to use to copy a file from a package into your output and I stumbled on this when setting build output to diagnostic. `AssetsFilePackageFolder` for this it points to my packages folder and so maybe you could use that if you need to copy a NuGet file to output dir.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that one out. In the mean time, I leave the question open so maybe someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. XML file is part of the package, but it won't get copied to the consumer's bin directory along with the package's dll. Have you found anything yet?

Comment: Looks like XML docs now need an explicit copy-to-output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696015/documentation-disappears-in-nuget-package

Comment: As mentioned before, turns out that it's not really a problem in the end.

Comment: @aybe did you managed to solve your problem. Iam stuck in the same problem. I have my nuget package included in my project. My package contains the assembly and the .xml doc file as well. But only my assembly (dll) is copied to the actual output Dir.

I run though the comments here but it seems that nothing of it solved the actual problem.
Any suggestions from your side?

Comment: Nope, haven't been able to.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this solution, or variations of it, in similar questions. It worked for me using .Net 8.

Add the below code to your `csproj` file

```
<Target Name="_ResolveCopyLocalNuGetPackageXmls" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" Condition="Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Note that it will copy all corresponding xml files, if they exist. If you don't want this, you may have to play around with the condition.

Note also that you may have to add it to some test project files as well. In my case I was consuming doc header for swagger and all my integration tests failed because the xml file I needed wasn't in the test project's bin folder

Comment: Thanks worked for me when I added this snippet to the csproj of the consuming project. Is there a way to specify it from the nuget package itself, so every consuming project will have this automatically?

Comment: @ArnonAxelrod not that I know of. Potentially the package publisher might not want to expose these things by default? Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I did :) Anyway, I am the package publisher, and I do want the XML to be published as part of my package. However I understand that you can't help me with this. Fortunately this is an internal package and I can just tell my internal customers to add this snippet to their .csproj files.