# Have a NuGet package output a file

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I have a Visual Studio project that I have made into a NuGet package.  The project has a file in it (called `SwaggerIndex.html`).  I have set that file to have the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer".  (I need this file to copy to the build folder on build.)

In that solution it works just fine.  (I created another project to test it, and when it references my project that has the `SwaggerIndex.html`, it outputs it to the build folder just fine.)

However, when I package it into a NuGet and pull it into another solution/project, the `SwaggerIndex.html` file is not output on build.

I am making my NuGet package by going to the project's "Package" properties tab and selecting "Generate NuGet package on build".  All projects involved are running .Net Core 3.1.

**How can I get my NuGet Package to create my `SwaggerIndex.html` file on build (like it does when it is just a normal project)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try these:

I have two solutions for you to solve the issue.

**Solution 1**

If you just want to install this nuget package only in new sdk projects(`Net Core` and `Net Standard` projects), you could use this

**1)** add these node in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="xxx\SwaggerIndex.html(the path of SwaggerIndex.html file in your project)" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\any">
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**2)** then repack your nuget project, and before you install the new version, you should first [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`

**Solution 2**

If you want this nuget package to copy `SwaggerIndex.html` file in both `Net Framework` and `Net Core` projects, you should use this:

**1)** add a file called `<package_id>.props` file in your nuget project. You should note that if your nuget package named as `SwaggerIndex.1.0.0.nupkg`, you should name the file as `SwaggerIndex.props` file so that it will work.

**In my side**, I put it into a folder called `build`.

[image]

**2)** then add these content in `SwaggerIndex.props` file,

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="CopyToOutputFolder" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\File\*.*"></File>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)"></Copy>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**3)** add these in `xxx.csproj` file of your nuget project.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="SwaggerIndex.html" Pack="true" PackagePath="File"></None>
        <None Include="build\SwaggerIndex.props" Pack="true" PackagePath="build"></None>   
</ItemGroup>
```

**4)** then repack your nuget package, before installing this new version of the nuget package, you should [first clean all nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

When you finishing installing the new version of the nuget package, click **Build** and the file will be copied into the main project.

[image]

Besides, there is also [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64160274/including-a-folder-in-nuget-package-and-have-it-install-into-project-as-file-ne/64167211#64167211) about this.

Comment: `PackageCopyToOutput` was the part I was missing!  Thank you!