# Copy JSON file to bin from class library nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I apologize for the vague title, but I am not sure how to phrase it.

I am working with a "custom" appsettings.json folder. The json file lives in the class library that is using it. I want to create a nuget package to install this class library but also make sure that appsettings.json is copied into the correct directory (if I am installing it in a console app, the build output directory).

I have seen one "answer"

[How can I set the 'copy to output directory' property in my nuspec file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747744/how-can-i-set-the-copy-to-output-directory-property-in-my-nuspec-file)

but I am using VS 2019 and .NET Standard 2.0. I am pretty frustrated so any help (even if told not possible) is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to install this nuget package only on net core projects, you could just add these node under the  net standard project's csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Update="xxx\appsettings.json" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\any;content">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then, repack the net standard project into a nuget package, before install it under a new project, you should [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

If you want to install this nuget package into a net framework project, you should try to use `<package_id>.props` file on the net standard2.0 lib project.

[Please try the function under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364415/have-a-nuget-package-output-a-file/64366618#64366618).

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Could you please update your answer and show how the Nuget would look like please?