# Copy nuget package content file (of type .exe) to output directory of project using that nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I have some project which has some exe as "dependency" and I build that project as nuget package from `.csproj` file

File looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    <PackageId>MyLib</PackageId>
    <Authors>me</Authors>
    <Company>me</Company>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="CliInterface\32BitInterface.exe" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="CliInterface\32BitInterface.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="3.3.0">
      <PrivateAssets>analyzers;build</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I use that nuget package inside some other solution I can see file is there
[image]

However it is not copyed to output folder.
In fact, to be correct it is when I run `Build` project from `Visual Studio`, but I use `dotnet build` command in my `CI/CD` environment and it is not copied to output when I run that command.

EDIT:
I also noticed that location of that exe is inside %USERPROFILE%.nuget folder
and also my csproj file (from other solution, that references that nuget package) has hardocoded path with my username inside it. I'm not sure why is that the case but don't like that

Comment: You may try this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx

Comment: Can you try removing the <None Remove="CliInterface\32BitInterface.exe" /> part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Instead**, try to use this

`<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>`

**Add** these on the `csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="CliInterface\32BitInterface.exe">
     <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
```

**And** then repack your lib project. When you try to install this new release version, please do not forget to [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**Besides**, this is also [a similar issue about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565696/copy-json-file-to-bin-from-class-library-nuget-package/65575438?).

Comment: This should be default option. What is the point of gaving content files which don't end up in output folder. And tnx :)

Comment: `PackageCopyToOutput` is for the content files from nuget packages being copied into the output folders pf the main project while `CopyToOutputDirectory` is for the internal files of the main projects being copied into the output folder.