# Visual Studio: Copy files into output with their package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, project-reference, packagereference

I have a project called "A" project, and it contain some files (like dll or others).

In my main project, I used "Project Reference" to reference this project, and add some context into the .csproj of A as follow:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="files\MyDll.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <TargetPath>MyDll.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

It's looked fine and the files were always copied to the output folder of my main project.

But after I make A project become a Nuget package and my main project use "Package Reference" to reference it, the files in A project are gone in output folder of my main project.

Does have any way to deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead**, you should use:

```
<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
```

Check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702783/copy-nuget-package-content-file-of-type-exe-to-output-directory-of-project-us).

**Update**

Use this instead:

```
<Content Include="files\MyDll.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\any\MyDll.dll;content\MyDll.dll">
          <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
</Content >
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But still one thing I need to fix is that I want the file path in output folder is "MyDll.dll" instead of "files\MyDll.dll". It seems need to modify something... My guess is "PackagePath" but I'm still trying.

Comment: @CYL, that  is right, You should use `PackagePath` to specify the path of the file from the nuget package into the main project. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It's fixed now. Thank you very much!