# Including Nuget Content Files to Target Projects Publish on .net Core Project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, csproj, dotnet-core-pack

before i start i must state that i pretty new to this nuget package things, so come basic at me.

My app has a core project to carry some .dll and .sql files and an api project. I have made the core project a nuget package with **dotnet pack** and automated it on github action so it creates a new version at all prs and pushes it to my private nuget server and it is all fine till here.

When i install this core package to my api project, there is no problem either. It installs successfully and my sql files shows up on the target project as i expected(but as linked sources).

[image: sql files linked source]

But when i try to publish this project with dotnet pack, the .sql files are not copied to output folder. I looked to the properties of the files and saw that their copy to output directory prop has been reset to do not copy and the file path was absolute.

[image]

My goal is to build and deploy this api with github actions so absolute paths are not acceptable and besides i don't want to arrange something in the target project manually.

I'm packing the core project with dotnet pack
I don't have any

- .nuspec file
- package config xml
- nuget config
- package metadata

or other things like than and i don't know how to use them.

I have tried adding to csproj file `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` and `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` things and they did not work.

I have tried adding to csproj file
[image]
and it did not work too.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps this will help [include-all-dependencies-using-dotnet-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396161/include-all-dependencies-using-dotnet-pack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is that you should write this node `<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>` to every content file of the nuget net core project:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Queries\Account\CheckAccountRef.sql">
<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
</Content>

.....
</ItemGroup>
```

**Then**, re-pack your nuget project with `dotnet pack` and then reinstall this new version into your main project. Before you install, you should delete the old caches under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.

There is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732327/visual-studio-copy-files-into-output-with-their-package/65732726#65732726) about this.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what i needed and i couldn't find it. I couldn't see this tag in documentations, is there a specific title or is it just me missing out?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package

Answer (score 1):

You can use .nuspec file to configure all your dependencies. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec

Comment: Thanks but with <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput> tag did the job.