# Create NuGet package that when installed copies content to $(OutputPath) regardless of machine

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to get a content file that is included with my NuGet package to be copied to the `$(OutputPath)` (in my case `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` where all the DLLs end up) of a target C# project when the target is built. This needs to work on developers' boxes *and* on build machines. Here's what I have so far.

I created a NuGet package project with a content node

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="testsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I am using the default values for the [pack target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target) inputs `IncludeContentInPack` and `ContentTargetFolders`, which are `true` and `content;contentFiles` respectively.

When I build the package, I get the following structure where `testsettings.json` appears in `contentFiles\any\netcoreapp3.1` and `content` folders of the `.nupkg`.

[image]

When I install the package into a target `.csproj`,

- the `testsettings.json file` is added to the project's root folder as expected
- the  `<PackageReference Include="..." Version="..."/>` line is added to the target `.csproj` as expected
- no entry appears in the target `.csproj` for `testsettings.json`

When I build the target project, the DLLs go to `$(OutputPath)` but `testsettings.json` is not copied there, which makes sense because the default for a **Content** node's action is **None**). However, I need it to act like `<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>`.

I thought, "OK I will manually change `testsettings.json` using the **Properties** window to **Copy if newer**":

[image]

This adds a node to the target `.csproj` that looks like:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="C:\redacted\path\to\nuget\cache\package.name\N.N.N\contentFiles\any\netcoreapp3.1\testsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

which works great for *my machine*. This will fail for any build machine and any other developer's machine because that path is *specific* to my machine.

How can I create the package so that when installing the package it will result in a repeatable way of getting `testsettings.json` in the right place?

In the course of researching this, I noticed that `testhost.exe` and `testhost.dll` somehow magically end up in the right spot even though their source NuGet package's `.nuspec` and structure are similar to mine. This has left me at bit of a loss on what I need to do to modify my NuGet package's `.nuspec`, `.nupkg`, build sequence, etc.

Preferable: Is there a way to do this, and if so how? Highly not preferable: Is there a manual change I can make in the target project such that I can get a reliable way of copying the file that works everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="XXXXX.json">
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>     
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

should meet your requirements.

In your NuGet project's `xxproj` file, add codes like above and use <**PackageCopyToOutput**>.

In the new project which you'd like to test, before installing your NuGet Package, remember to [clear the NuGet Package cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first, and then install your NuGet package and build your project, check if the XXXXX.json file has been copied to Output.

Similar thread: [Copy JSON file to bin from class library nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565696/copy-json-file-to-bin-from-class-library-nuget-package/65575438?).