# Copy static files to project root directory from nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to build a nuget package in .Net Core for that I create a .net core class
Library project and also add 2  json config files for configuration which I also
add into package .

I want ,when I add the package into my project then the 2 json files placed into project folder root
or where I set the path.

for this I do following steps ,but not working,**files added as a link** ,my **requirement
is add files physically into directory**

[image]

**Create a class library project**

[image]

**Set JSON file property**

[image]

**Set package options**

[image]

**after adding the package ,json files add as link.**

I want a less complex straight forward solution.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353505/4336330) by Mr Qian ,which is solve my problem.

Also another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64366618/4336330)